# 歩いてた what is form of verb?

Tags: verbs, form

I have seeing in some song this:

> いつもひとりで歩いてた

How was this form formed? (歩いてた) Explain tocme please.

Answer (score 1):

「歩いてた」is nothing but the casual contraction of 歩いていた which is「歩く」in past「ている」form.

Here are more useful contractions:

「ている」->「てる」->「てん」

「ていた」->「てた」